# A better approach to combine multiple MySQL tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join

I am developing a system which generates an ID for all users that visit my website. If the user creates an account, applies for credit, buys a products... etc, it links the user information with this ID across multiple tables on the database. My problem is, combining all the information takes a long time as we have over 60,000 thousand records as of this moment. I previously created a VIEW which completely killed the performance time (taking up to 3 minutes) so I decided to instead create a query to fetch the data and combine the non-empty fields with PHP, which came up with a total of 10-15 seconds using pagination as well. I would like it to improve it more if possible. Any suggestions?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    u.user_id,
    u.operating_system_name AS os,
    u.browser_name AS browser,
    u.ip_address,
    u.hardware_type AS hardware,
    u.city AS city,
    u.state AS state,
    u.country AS country,
    u.date AS date,

    m.id_member AS member,
    s.id_supplier AS supplier,
    c.id_entry AS credit,
    p.id_partner AS partner,
    cu.employee_ID AS careersus,
    cm.empleado_ID AS careersmx,
    o.id_order     AS orderid,

    o.recipient_name AS fn_o,
    m.first_name AS fn_m,
    c.first_name AS fn_c,
    p.first_name AS fn_p,
    s.contact_first_name AS fn_s,
    cu.firstname AS fn_cu,
    cm.nombre AS fn_cm,

    o.last_name AS ln_o,
    m.last_name AS ln_m,
    c.last_name AS ln_c,
    p.last_name AS ln_p,
    s.contact_last_name AS ln_s,
    cu.lastname AS ln_cu,
    cm.apellido AS ln_cm

    FROM tb_users_ids AS u 
    LEFT JOIN tb_orders AS o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tb_members AS m ON u.user_id = m.user_id
    LEFT JOIN financing AS c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tb_partners AS p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN suppliers AS s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tb_careers_us AS cu ON cu.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tb_careers_mx AS cm ON cm.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE u.user_id<>''
    ORDER BY u.date DESC
    LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$rowsperpage;
```

Comment: Are the user_id's in tables made index? That makes a big difference

Comment: @LuckyMurari no, the only table that has user_id as index is tb_users_ids

Comment: We can illustrate the problem, and the solution, using just half as many tables, and some sample data, and the desired result. But the key is indexes. With all that in mind, See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The query time is 100% related to your indexes. Fix those, and you could have millions of rows, and you wouldn't see anything > 100ms. You should either post your full schema (Just the database, not the data), or consider hiring someone to consult and fix up the data.

Comment: YES IT WAS TOTALLY RELATED TO THE INDEXES, THANK YOU SO MUCH :D

Comment: @LilithDeficiency Since this solved your issue, can you please mark my answer as accepted now?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create indexes to all fields which you compare.
So if your query is like `table1.user_id = table2.user_id` define index for `user_id` in your table1 and table2.
Do it at all tables.

Then it will very be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Please make user_id as an index for all your tables. This will make your query much faster